# Is it possible to get javascript data from web to application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I need to get a list of innerHTML strings from a website (for example facebook) to my .NET application.
Is there a way to get results from the following function into my application (i would put this data into a list) :

```
var data = new Array();
for(i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName("class-name").length;i++)
    data.push(document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[i].innerHTML);
```

The code above outputs exactly the data i need, now my question is if it's possible to somehow get this data into my c# list?

This is how I'd like it to look :

```
var JS_DATA = data;                             //get the js array as a variable
static List<string> data = new List<string>();  //make a new list

foreach (string str in JS_DATA)
    data.Add(String.Format("{0}", str));        //add the whole js array to the list
```

Comment: Look at documentation around posting form data to a controller for .net MVC. That'll get you most of the way there. https://jonhilton.net/2017/08/17/how-to-get-data-from-an-html-form-to-your-asp.net-mvc-core-controller/ then look at how to make it so when those html strings are updated they get sent to the form action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

see hidden Field array_store

Client side:

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var array_store;
         window.onload = function () {
             array_store = document.getElementById("array_store");
             document.getElementById("array_disp").innerHTML = array_store.value;
         };
         function UpdateArray() {
             var arr;
             if (array_store.value == "") {
                 arr = new Array();
             } else {
                 arr = array_store.value.split(",");
             }
             arr.push((arr.length + 1).toString());
             array_store.value = arr.join(",");
         };
    </script>
  </head>
   <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <span id="array_disp"></span>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="UpdateArray()" />
    <input type="hidden" id="array_store" name = "ArrayStore" value = '<%=this.ArrayStore %>' />
    </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

C#:

```
   protected string ArrayStore = "";
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      this.ArrayStore = Request.Form["ArrayStore"];
   }
```